# Why is the attribute selector not working with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get all elements that have `data-maxlength` assigned to them with any value in the attribute. Then, every time the value of the text input or textarea changes, I want to display the `length` of the input in a tooltip along with the `maxlength` value ( x / 250 characters) in a Bootstrap tooltip.

When I type in the input, nothing happens, no tooltip, no errors. Not even my `console.log` message appears in the console. What is wrong with this code?

The jQuery / JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-maxlength]').find().each(function(){
        console.log('hello');
        $(this).on('keyup', function(){
            console.log('hi!');
            $(this).data('toggle', 'tooltip').data('placement', 'bottom').attr('title', $(this).val().length + ' / ' + $(this).data('maxlength'));
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="description" data-maxlength="250"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `.find()`

```
$('[data-maxlength]').each(function(){
```

But seems you are taking it wrong, you should bind the event on the selector itself that also return a collection and `$(this)` will be your current element in action:

```
$('[data-maxlength]').on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).data({
       'toggle':'tooltip', 
       'placement' : 'bottom'
    }).attr('title', $(this).val().length + ' / ' + $(this).data('maxlength'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the jQuery method **[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** without selector you should add selector to it `.find(selector)` or remove it at all :

```
$('[data-maxlength]').find(selector).each(function(){
//OR
$('[data-maxlength]').each(function(){
```

**NOTE :** you shouldn't define event inside `each()` method and it's better to use `input` event instead of `keyup` when you track input changes :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-maxlength]').on('input', function(){
        $(this).data({ toggle: "tooltip", placement: "bottom"})
               .attr('title', $(this).val().length + ' / ' + $(this).data('maxlength'));
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select elements which has a value for `data-maxlength`. You can use the following. You can use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) here instead of [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

> trying to get all elements that have data-maxlength assigned to them with any value in the attribute

```
$('[data-maxlength]').filter(function(){
    $(this).data('maxlength') != '';
}).each(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find it by below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($(".devTxt").attr("data-maxlength"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4eekb7jz/